# Open Iframe Popups in New Iframe with sandbox attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

*Brief overview:*

Trying to find a creative solution using javascript/jquery for a situation I am stuck in where the new popup needs to be opened up in a new iframe with sandbox attributes rather than new window or tab which is the default behaviour now.

*Detailed Explanation:*

My page A.html embeds B.html in iframe like this:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" src='http://b.html/' width='100%' height='100%' name='bfr' frameborder='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' id="inneriframe" class="popup" scrolling='yes' webkitallowfullscreen='true' mozallowfullscreen='true' allowfullscreen='true'></iframe>
```

Now, this iframe is kind of authentication token generation page which when clicked leads to page c.html in a new window.

I am trying to open c.html in the same page within a new iframe with the same attributes of b.html. The tricky part is a.html is the only page in my control and rest is a remote domain so cannot make any changes on the remote pages.

Any possible ideas?

Comment: You can access the attributes of the iFrame since you can even dynamically create it. However you are talking about getting a token from the third party origin (XSS?). This may lead you into trouble with the "Same Origin Policy", take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy - The usual approach is to  use (or create and then use) an API written for your purpose. You could pull the page content with CURL serverside and pass the session ID, but this only works if there's no IP check etc on the remote site (Your server does most likely not have your website visitors IP).

Comment: yes, well aware of the Same-origin_policy, which is why its the trickiest part of this challenge. But I am not trying to take away anything from the remote url, just want its behaviour of opening up c.html in a new window to be opened up in iframe rather than a new window. In other words, compose all popups coming from iframe into new iframes. And yes, CURL is the server side solution to go for in this situation but I am trying to build a serverless solution for this situation.

Comment: You aren't (shouldn't technically) be able to externally change the way how B opens C. Let it be a form or href using `target="_blank"` or let it be window.open, both would be an XSS violation. You are not supposed to edit B (different origin). Only other clientside way I could think of that would work is giving the iframe a parameter on loading that tells the iframe how C is to be opened, . e.g. otherdomain/b.php?target=_self - but of course this needs to be supported by B on the other origin. Since you left that entirely open, we're not able to test that for you nor to look it up in any way.